# Android Touch Gestures in Custom View - Null Object Reference

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to develop an android app which allows users to draw on the phone screen and also display the kind of touch gestures(tap, long press, scroll etc) being used. So I believe to display the trace of the fingers, we need to use a view. I have created two separate apps - one which displays the touch gesture being performed and other one which allows the user to draw.

Now I want to combine both. How do I implement it? Drawing is done on a custom view while other one is in an activity.

I tried implementing the gesture display function on the view. I was getting the below error:

*view.GestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference*

Below is my code:

```
public class Tdraw extends View implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private TextPaint mTextPaint;
    private float mTextWidth;
    private float mTextHeight;

    private TextView gesText;
    private GestureDetectorCompat gDetector;


    public Tdraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);

        gesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gesText);
        gDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);
        gDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    public Tdraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public Tdraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs, defStyle);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        gesText.setText("Single Tap");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        gesText.setText("Double Tap");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        gesText.setText("Scroll");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        gesText.setText("Long Press");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        gesText.setText("Fling");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public  boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.anurooppv.gesturerec.Tdraw android:background="#ccc" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingBottom="40dp"
        app:exampleDimension="24sp" app:exampleColor="#33b5e5" app:exampleString="Hello, Tdraw"
        app:exampleDrawable="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Perform a touch gesture"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/gesText"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

What could be the reason for error? The same code in an activity works fine but here it fails. How can I combine the two functionalities? Thanks in advance.